# Comment the if statement and the matching endif keyword

Tags: vim, sed, regular-expression

In vim, I can find the matching `if` statement and prepend the appropriate comment symbol. (e.g. %s/.*alarm.*/#\0/g), but then I am left with dangling `endif`s that I have to find manually. I could simplify the process by using macro, but I could I achieve this with `sed` (more specifically one in vim)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a simple regular expression is dealing with nested conditionals; you cannot simply search for the next `endif` and comment it out. Fortunately, the *matchit* plugin that comes with Vim has this problem solved (for many filetypes); when on the `if`, the `%` mapping will take you to the corresponding `endif`.

Combine that with a plugin like *NERDCommenter*, and you can easily build a mapping for it:

```
:nmap <Leader>cif <Leader>cc%<Leader>cc
```

Comment: Thank you. I never thought about using those plugins that way!